# Markers incorrectly changing location on zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a set of markers being added to a map at zoom level 15. The markers lat and lng are currently set to the 6th decimal place.

When I zoom in or out the marker locations are moving out of their correct position. Do i need to remove and redraw the markers at each zoom level? do I need to increase the accuracy of my coords? this is driving me crazy...

Test page: http://m.uwosh.edu/api/v1.0/map/
click on the yellow icon in the bottom bar.

I'm creating my markers like so:

```
function createMarker(data, type) 
{
  var posn = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat,data.lng);
  var title = data.title;
  var image,shadow,shape;
  if (data.typeId === '101') {
      image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/api/v1.0/map/images/buildings.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(24, 28),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
      new google.maps.Point(0, 28));
    shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/api/v1.0/map/images/shadow-buildings.png',
      // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
      // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
      new google.maps.Size(39, 28),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 28));

  } 
  var markerOptions = {
    position: posn,
    title: title,
    shadow: shadow,
    icon: image
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

    // could add event handler here

    //add marker to array for latter use
    if (type === 'building') {
       buildingMarkers.push(marker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to add/remove the markers as the markers are placed with the lat/long location.

Perhaps some code may help us figure this out.

Comment: sure I've added a link to my test site in the body

Comment: giving you credit as your answer is right. If you don't mess up the icon attachment point it won't move.

Comment: I'm not sure if they are really "moving" I tested your page on chrome. And the markers aren't exactly moving. They are staying in place of the fix, where they are told to be drawn via lat/long locations. Because you're zooming in on a different part of the map, expanding the viewable area, the markers need to keep their location relative to where you are zooming into.  If you use your mouse wheel and zoom in on a marker, you'll notice that that marker doesn't move. But if you zoom in on a different area it does because it's keeping it's lat/long location defined by your code.

Comment: @JKM, can you clarify?  I'm having the same problem and I can't figure out if there's a fix based on your last comment. I'm setting the marker position to a LatLng, and when I drag the map (so the markers are off the screen) and zoom, then drag the map back to the original view, the marker images are offset by the distance that I dragged the map.  The actual coordinates of the marker haven't chnaged, just the displayed location of the marker images.

Comment: @byron In h3r2on's case the markers were given the wrong Lat/Long values. The markers simply don't move. Have you tested in a different browser?